# Getting tickets to Antelope Canyon

Tags: usa, tickets, grand-canyon, arizona

I assume [this](https://www.antelopecanyon.com) is the official website for Antelope Canyon tours. (I'm talking about what is classified there as sightseer's tours.) If there is no availability on this website for a particular date/dates (in 2019; to be specific, at the end of December), I was wondering if it is possible to get tickets elsewhere (including buying them physically in Page)? Also, if there is no availability on the website for a particular date right now, does it make sense to keep checking the website to see whether new tickets have been added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that the cited website is *the* official website for Antelope Canyon tours is false. I found [a list of companies](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11l-_leXnVQMMYFDJwogKOK-m6l0kGHdKNr0t2-U1kdA/pubhtml) which offer tours to Antelope Canyon (note that the prices listed in the table are not accurate as of today). It looks like one can almost always find availability for any date since there are more than 10 companies organizing tours.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple Antelope Canyons you can visit.
Examples are:

- Upper Antilope Canyon: https://navajotours.com
- Lower Antilope Canyon: https://lowerantelope.com
- Antelope Canyon X: https://www.antelopecanyon-x.com

Here is the list from the Navajo Nation Parks & Recreation (They oversee all Navajo Tribal Parks on the Navajo Nation Reservation): https://navajonationparks.org/guided-tour-operators/antelope-canyon-tour-operators/

During the summer the more popular are very crowded. (There are some nice videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIRmlPFypwA) showing how uncomfortable it is for the visitors).

I personally went on the "photo tour" in the Antelope Canyon X. As it is less popular we had enough time to take a lot of good photos. We also intended to go to the Upper Antilope Canyon, but the staff was so rude, that we decided we did not want to spend time with these people.